# mariadb (in docker) corruption. Fix or reset database?

Tags: docker, mariadb

I am using the official mariadb docker image, and after updating to latest version (10.5.8), I started getting errors about corruption (see logs below). Since this persists when I downgrade to earlier mariadb versions, I guess it's a database corruption?

Is there a way to fix it? and if not, how do I just reset the database (it's not the end of the world to lose data in database, but it is if the mariadb container does not start to work).

logs (this repeats):

```sh
2020-11-18 15:45:35+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 1:10.5.8+maria~focal started.
2020-11-18 15:45:35+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
2020-11-18 15:45:35+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 1:10.5.8+maria~focal started.
2020-11-18 15:45:36 0 [Note] mysqld (mysqld 10.5.8-MariaDB-1:10.5.8+maria~focal) starting as process 1 ...
2020-11-18 15:45:36 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2020-11-18 15:45:36 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2020-11-18 15:45:36 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2020-11-18 15:45:36 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2020-11-18 15:45:36 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE4.2 crc32 instructions
2020-11-18 15:45:36 0 [Note] mysqld: O_TMPFILE is not supported on /tmp (disabling future attempts)
2020-11-18 15:45:36 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 134217728, chunk size = 134217728
2020-11-18 15:45:36 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2020-11-18 15:45:36 0 [Note] InnoDB: If the mysqld execution user is authorized, page cleaner thread priority can be changed. See the man page of setpriority().
2020-11-18 15:45:36 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery from checkpoint LSN=20174219501,20174219501
2020-11-18 15:45:36 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting final batch to recover 3205 pages from redo log.
2020-11-18 15:45:36 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Not applying INSERT_REUSE_REDUNDANT due to corruption on [page id: space=0, page number=2062]
2020-11-18 15:45:36 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Set innodb_force_recovery=1 to ignore corruption.
2020-11-18 15:45:36 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Not applying INSERT_REUSE_REDUNDANT due to corruption on [page id: space=0, page number=2062]
2020-11-18 15:45:36 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Set innodb_force_recovery=1 to ignore corruption.
2020-11-18 15:45:36 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Not applying INSERT_REUSE_REDUNDANT due to corruption on [page id: space=0, page number=2062]
2020-11-18 15:45:36 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Set innodb_force_recovery=1 to ignore corruption.
2020-11-18 15:45:36 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Not applying INSERT_REUSE_REDUNDANT due to corruption on [page id: space=0, page number=2062]
2020-11-18 15:45:36 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Set innodb_force_recovery=1 to ignore corruption.
2020-11-18 15:45:36 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Plugin initialization aborted with error Data structure corruption
2020-11-18 15:45:36 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
2020-11-18 15:45:37 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
2020-11-18 15:45:37 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
2020-11-18 15:45:37 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2020-11-18 15:45:37 0 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
2020-11-18 15:45:37 0 [ERROR] Aborting
```

And using this docker-compose.yaml:

```
  hass_db:
    image: mariadb:latest
    # image: mariadb:10.5.4
    # image: mariadb:10.4.14
    container_name: hass_db
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: Maria4sud0
      MYSQL_DATABASE: homeassistant
      MYSQL_USER: homeassistant
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: Maria4HAss
    restart: on-failure
    volumes:
      - /mnt/data/docker/hass_db:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
      mynet:
        ipv4_address: 172.11.0.7
```

Comment: Better you can take a backup of the data and then reset and after that restore the data which you have taken as backup

Comment: With this version 10.5.8 release date of 11 Nov 2020, you are on the bleeding edge and should expect to report problems and wait for fixes.  In the future consider installing newer release only after at least 3 months (preferably 6 months) of allowing other people to find and report problems.

Comment: Good to know, @WilsonHauck. I kind of assumed that "latest" was the latest stable, since there was no "stable" tag, and there is a "beta" tag. Does this mean there's not way to automatically stay up to date with latest stable version?

Comment: You have choices.  Be conservative and avoid the bleeding edge (early adopters) and the reporting / waiting responsibility when you are pressed for time every day.